# Trouble deep cloning an array object

Tags: java

I believe my code is wrong but could someone correct me on my error. I am trying to deep clone an array of objects but class A doesn't seem to be a deep copy as i am having trouble with it. Could some please help. I have trouble copying the array A.

```
Class A implements Cloneable{
private int year;
private double data;

A(int year, double data)
 {
   setInt(year);
   setDouble(data);
 }
public void setInt(int year)
{
  this.year = year;
}
public void setDouble(double data)
 {
 this.data = data; 
  }
public int getYear()
 {
return year;
}
public double getData()
{
return data; 
} 
 public Object clone()
{
 A clonedA = new A(this.getYear(), this.getData());
return clonedA;
}}

 class B implements Cloneable{
 private A[] a;
 private String name;
 private int arraylength;
 private int index;

public B(String name, int length)
 {
  this.name = name;
  this.arraylength = length;
  a = new A[array.length];
  index = 0;
 }

 public void addToA(int year, double data)
 {
   a[index] = new A(year, data);
   index++;
  } 
  public String getName(){
     return name;  }
    public int getLength(){
    return array length;}

   public void setName(String name)
   {
    this.name= name
   }
  public Object clone()
 {
  B clonedB = new B(this.getName(), this.getLength());

   for(A clonedArray: a)
  {
 clonedB.addToA(clonedArray.getYear(), clonedArray.getData());
   }
  return clonedB;
 }
```

Comment: This shouldn't even compile - `A(int double, double data)` isn't valid Java (note the `int double`). Can you please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I believe A(int double, double data) should be A(int year, double data) instead

Comment: Also, your clone method in A isn't returning anything even though it should return an Object.

Comment: @turingcomplete that was a typo error regarding not returning the object. My question was regarding cloning the object array a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clone method in class B seems to be wrong: 
I suggest you do sth like

```
public Object clone()
{
 B newB = new B(this.getName(), this.getLength());
 for(int i =0;i<newB.a.length;i++)
   {
      newB.a[i] = a[i];
    }
    return newB;
  }
```

You could also try a copy constructor;